# Android Polyline not showing in release apk

Tags: java, android, google-maps, kotlin, google-maps-api-3

I'm creating polyline route with using google directions API, I'm also trying to animate the route line with using MapAnimator from this link

https://github.com/tintinscorpion/Dual-color-Polyline-Animation/blob/master/uberpolylineanimation/src/main/java/com/logicbeanzs/uberpolylineanimation/MapAnimator.java

this looks nice when i debug the app , it animates well, but creatong release  apk , no animation and no route line shown totaly

Comment: Can you please share your code and any errors you're getting? Also is your API key restricted? If so, did you add the sha-1 fingerprint for your release certificate? See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key#fingerprint

Comment: thanks even, I solved the issue

Comment: Glad to hear, please consider answering your own question for the community's sake. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the only issue was i was using a key for which directions api was not enabled. I solved it by changing api key with followings enables/added.

1. Billing enabled
2. Maps SDk for android (to show map)
3. Directions API (get polyline/routes data)
4. Places API (if you are using places search or similar)
5. Release Signing SHA-1 fingerprint (if key is restricted)

Path for file (app\src\release\res\values\google_maps_api.xml).